# as3 air current time and storing data

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air

I am currently creating a mobile application in air. One of the function is to sent the user a message a day and that message is stored locally so the user will not get a different message on the same day.
  After some research, I believe I can achieve this function through sqlite and maybe native access. Can someone point me to a direction for documentation and maybe some samples please, much thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of data are you going to store? a simple string/XML/JSON? or a more complex datatype?

Comment: use Date.getTime() this will give you an unique number representing the exact time in milliseconds. Google AS3 docs and find the SQLite classes and docs. Store in SQLite either as INTEGER or TEXT but if you retrieve SQLITE INTEGER store it in a Number as3 type not uint, if stored as TEXT then convert and store in uint.

Comment: just simple string, not objects